# How to validate the address fields in scala?

Tags: validation, scala

I am new to scala . I want to validate address module which contains the following sub-fields and their validation requirement:
office no:must contain alphanumeric value (e.g. D-20),
Floor no:Must contain only digits less than 150,
Building name :Can contain alphanumeric value.,
Area:Must have alphabets(e.g. Mumbai),
Country :Must have only alphabets,
zip code: Must have 6 digit value.

It will be very helpful for me if someone suggest me any link to read for these kind of validations.
Thank u in advance. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to validate very simple things, you should take a look at using [regex](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex) to solve your problem.  For more complicated languages, scala has a library called [parser combinators](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers), but it is almost certainly overkill for your problem.